# jQuery price range slider with two handlers. editing min and max values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please i want to need a price range slider with two handlers and editing the  min and max values.when i inserted the values in min and max input field then the price slider moved . see the demo on https://www.daraz.pk/mens-t-shirts/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Range Slider</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <div data-role="rangeslider">
        <label for="price-min">Price:</label>
        <input type="range" name="price-min" id="price-min" value="200" min="0" max="1000">
        <label for="price-max">Price:</label>
        <input type="range" name="price-max" id="price-max" value="800" min="0" max="1000">
      </div>
        <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
        <p>The range slider can be useful for allowing users to select a specific price range when browsing products.</p>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this demo.

1. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider_range)
2. [jQueruUI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)
3. [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/)

Regards

Comment: Same way you can use noUISlider plugin http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Comment: Thanks @NitinDhomse Updated my answer. :)